# How to switch input language on Caps Lock in Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome 3.16

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 15.10

Previous 15.04 version had an easy solution to change language on Caps Lock in 
`System > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Typing`

After update to 15.10 bind Caps Lock to 'Switch to next input source' is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnome tweak tool GUI check:

`Gnome tweak tool > typing > Caps Lock key behavior check Caps Lock is disabled`.

Terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-input-source "['VoidSymbol']"`

Comment: I've tried this on Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3 and it doesn't work.

Comment: @CristianaNicolae Answer above for the 15.10 version only. 

Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome 3 just ```Settings > Typing > Modifiers-only switch to next source```.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I've finally managed to solve my problem! Here are all the steps which I've done in Ubuntu 16.04: `All Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts tab> Typing > Modifiers-only switch to next source > click on Disable and choose, from the menu, the desired key combination (Ant+Shift)`. I've posted it for the benefit of other Ubuntu users. Thanks, once again!