# Fast switch input source via CapsLock button in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, 17.10, capslock

I updated my Ubuntu version to 17.10 and I want to configure switching to next input source via CapsLock button. I tried to set CaspLock in keyboard setting, but I cant because nothing happening.

I did actions explained here [How to switch input language on Caps Lock in Ubuntu 15.10 Gnome 3.16](https://askubuntu.com/questions/692931/how-to-switch-input-language-on-caps-lock-in-ubuntu-15-10-gnome-3-16) and it works, but now when I switching input source I see a pop-up (like as pop-up that shows switching application windows) and must wait a few seconds until it disappears.

How I can resolve my problem?

Comment: Here is the solution that finally worked for me for Unbuntu 20.04 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123163/modeless-stateless-layout-language-switching-with-caps-lock-again-18-04-lts-bi

Answer (score 43, accepted):

By trial and (a lot of) error, this works for me (I'm not sure whether the first three steps are required).

1. Open `Settings` (the default system setting app).
2. Go to `Devices -> Keyboard` and press `Reset All...`.
3. Close the `Settings` app.
4. Install `gnome-tweak-tool` and open it.
5. Go to `Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options`
6. Seek for `Switching to another layout` and unchecked every options under that setting.
7. Restart the `Tweaks` app.
8. Repeat step 5-6 again, only this time make sure you check the one and only `Caps Lock` option.
9. Close the `Tweaks` app, now you should use the caps lock button to switch language without popup menu to delay the input :D

Comment: What option I must check in tweak app? I checked CapsLock option "Capslock is disabled", after I used Casplock button to switch language and button what determined like "0xff" and It doesnt work.

Comment: Hmm, during my process I didn't encounter "Capslock is disabled" at all. Sorry I don't know how to help you.

Comment: Im sorry, I read inattentively, It works, big thanks.

Comment: "Go to Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options" there it is! THANK YOU! When upgrading to 20.04 I chose Caps lock to switch input sources. However, this actually just caused capslock to get stuck, meaning I was screaming the whole time, both literally and well... literally :-D

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 22.04.3 as well. Thanks you! `gnome-tweak-tool` can be install using `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like the popup, install the [Quick Lang Switch](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4559/quick-lang-switch/) Gnome-shell extension to avoid the delay of the switcher popup - now switching languages happens instantaneously.
Plus, it does not define a *custom-shortcut*, so all customizations with `gnome-tweak-tool`/`setxkbmap` in X11 or *Wayland* still work fine.

> **NOTE:** this is not a solution for using **[CapsLock]** as the switch key, nor addressing "mode errors" (ie. when the switch key is pressed multiple times).

***Disclaimer**: I am the developer of the Quick Lang Switch...*